# Whole row editable on click of a row in GWT editable grid

Tags: gwt

I need to implement a functionality like onclick of a row, whole row must become editable.
For eg: Currently I have 4 columns, each column have edittext cell as the datatype (element). Onclick of a row, each edittext cells must be in edit mode (input mode). Can this implementation be done??
Currently when we click on each component it opens in input mode, but i need to have input mode for all cells on click of a row.

Please suggest and give some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the job with some things in the "databinding" part of GWT :

[com.google.gwt.editor.client.Editor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/class-use/Editor.html)